# copy content when columns contains a word NO in different format

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I have a file where column "b" has got "NO" written in multiple ways as below.

-No , : No , --no , : no, -No and many more

So whenever the entry is "NO" written in any of the above form then that respective row should be copied to another sheet.

Also only specific columns with headings like "major IT skills", "total experience " , "current location " etc from that row should be copied to required sheet. Not the entire row.

I have shared the following test sheet

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18crwT3dICqAOD464D1sR3pObmPiJUhlk1KCaZvtnNtA/edit?usp=sharing

Thanx in advance